# configure Zend server CE if a machine doesn't support ipv6

Tags: zend-server, zend-server-installation

I have installed latest Zend Server CE in my notebook (it has Win 7 installed) and then
I installed it on my desktop machine. But when you start server controller there is an alert saying Connection refused (or timed out)

What's the problem?
When I start server `http://localhost:10081/ZendServer/`

the following message appears

`Internal Server Error`

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

`Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.`

`More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

and apache works well in the following address http://localhost:81

when i `telnet localhost 10081` there is a reply !!!

I found from the inet http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=7518 that it's because of not having ipv6 support, I am running windows xp3 on my desktop
how to disable default ipv6 support in Zend conf?

how to fix this problem or should I switch to win 7 (my desktop)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, on Debian Squeeze after an upgrade to the currently latest version of Zend from the zend apt repo, [deb http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/deb server non-free] . The Zend gui fails.

zend-server-ce-php-5.3  5.5.0+b63

Log in /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/logs/php.log throws this exception.

```
[10-Jan-2012 11:20:03] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown application version' in /usr/local/zend/gui/application/CheckDependencies.php:28
 Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/zend/gui/html/index.php(16): CheckDependencies::getChecker('INSTALLATION_PL...')
#1 {main}
 thrown in /usr/local/zend/gui/application/CheckDependencies.php on line 28
```

The problem is the zend-server.ini file in /usr/local/zend/gui/application/data/zend-server.ini But after doing the changes shown below it seems to work ok again.

```
--- zend-server.ini 2012-01-05 16:45:29.000000000 +0100
+++ zend-server.ini 2012-01-10 12:01:37.000000000 +0100
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@

[zendServer]
version = 5.6.0
-edition = INSTALLATION_PLACEHOLDER_GUI_EDITION
+edition = CE
devEnv=0
```

Comment: This solved the same problem on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server after updating Zend Server CE.

Answer (score 0):

This is Zend's default error message, meaning you have some error in the php script you are running. By default, your php.ini file in Zend is configured to report errors, but not specifically state what errors had occurred, which makes this case hard to diagnose. My recommendation is that if you are using this server for debugging purposes, go to your Zend php.ini file (typically C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\etc) and search for "display_errors" and change its default value from "Off" to "On". This will allow you to see the specific error PHP is encountering rather than getting the generic Zend error message.

Comment: I did this! No success ! Zend controller is not working ! When i start send server aforementioned error still pops out !

Comment: Well I'm assuming you've played around with that second to last post in the forum link you included, so my suggestion would be to check the actual location of the Zend Server files are in Program Files/Zend, make sure your php.ini value for "open_basedir" is correct (the default is none), and make sure your Zend properties are configured to use port 10081 and ip 127.0.0.1 (this is found in the system tray). Simple Apache server or computer restarts always help, and if all else fails it may be an incorrect install, in which case try re-installing the server from scratch.